# Dart - How to Insert "$" word in String?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I'm currently creating an simple application with flutter(Dart). And when i want to create the AppBar widget, i cant give it names with '$'. Because, same like Kotlin..Dart is using '$' for summoning an identifier.

Any solution?

```
var _appbar = AppBar(
  title: Text("How I Made $100"), //$ is the error
);
```

Answer (score 41):

The dollar sign is a special character, so if you want it to be ignored you have to escape it with a `\`.

For example:

```
void main() {
  print("This string contains a dollar \$ign");
}
```

See [this gist](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/315f3e6645e396f9666f0d37ad529de0).

Comment: You can also prefix the string with r, as in `r"How I Made $100"`.